# Validating values of text strings with DTD

Tags: xml, validation, dtd

Can I have a dtd file check that the values of numbers are between specified values?

Maybe, make sure that

```
<x>5</x>
```

has a value between 1 and 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is one of the many restrictions of DTDs that caused people to design more powerful schema languages like XSD.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't allow you to specify or inspect the contents of a `#PCDATA` element. It's atomic for DTD's purposes.